# In C++, why does checking if a variable is nullptr may result in Access violation error?

Tags: c++

I am primarily a C# programer with often expedtions to C++ land and some stuff I just don't comprehend.

I have a class that has some FFmpeg object as member variable in .h file initialized like this:

```
AVFormatContext* formatContext = nullptr;
```

In the destructor of the class at one point I am checking if this object is nullptr like this:

```
    if(formatContext != nullptr)
        avformat_close_input(&formatContext);
```

Sadly, the if line causes the following exception:

```
Invalid argumentException thrown at 0x00007FFEA696920A (avformat-60.dll) in Blabla.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000
```

Why is it possible in C++ that a mere check for nullptr causes such an exception ?

I mean I am not trying to use the object, I am just checking is the addresss a nullptr.
I am not even checking for "validity" for the lack of a better word (so is this the "same" object that I think it is or has the address been messed up).

When I see **access violation** exception it seems to me like someone kidnapped this object and in its place is now potatos, but surely this is not possible ?

**Edit**

Let me ask you this, we are talking about modern (C++ 17) C++ and note that *av_stuff* is mostly FFmpeg related library calls.
Is my logic and perception of the problem in the comments below correct ?

```
AVFormatContext* formatContext = nullptr; // formatContext is ok and initialized as nullptr
...
avformat_fill_the_context_(&formatContext) //formatcontex has been "filled", so its not nullptr anymore but points to a valid object
...
av_do_somestuff(formatContext) //Some call that MESSES UP THE POINTER
...
if(formatContext != nullptr)  //here I get the exception, but my object was messed up earlier
```

Is my thought train correct, does stuff happen like this ?

Comment: `if(formatContext != nullptr)` -- This does not check if the pointer is actually valid.  This type of check is only good if you can guarantee there are no other issues in your program w.r.t pointer management.  -- *In the destructor of the class* -- Maybe the object itself is invalid.  Anything you do within an invalid object is invalid.

Comment: Don't forget a huge problem in C++ is having *uninitialized* values is a perpetual problem, so check that this is, for sure, initialized properly, and never assigned from an uninitialized value.

Comment: _"I have a class that has some FFmpeg object as member variable in .h file initialized like this"_ - It'd be more useful to see the actual definition of the class in a [mre].

Comment: In other words, unless the logic of your program has set `formatContext` to a `nullptr`, and your test relies on the logic "working correctly", then this test makes sense.  Otherwise, if you have that test for `nullptr` "just in case", that is a red flag that something may be amiss.  For example, if the pointer pointed to a dynamically allocated instance, and that instance is destroyed, the pointer value may look valid, but it is not valid.  Testing for `nullptr` isn't going to help you in that scenario.

Comment: `//formatcontex has been "filled"` Are you sure? `av_do_somestuff(formatContext)` is not protected by `if(formatContext != nullptr)`...

Comment: In situations like this, I often find that sprinkling some temporary debug-prints like `printf("the current value of the pointer is %p\n", formatContext);` at various places around the problem is often quite enlightening, in that it shows me whether the pointer is NULL or non-NULL, where in the execution-flow has been modified, and so on.

Comment: If `if(formatContext != nullptr)` throws an access violation, `this` pointer might be wrong - maybe you're destructing an object the second time or something like this.

Comment: Why dont you use address sanitizer, it might show you that av_do_somestuff actually is writing over memory or doing some other bad stuff.

Comment: As a general rule, evaluating `formatContext != nullptr` (where `formatContext` is a pointer) should not cause an access violation.   If it does, it means that some other part (or parts!) of your program or DLL have introduced undefined behaviour.   The possibilities are endless - the containing object has been destroyed twice (e.g. via `delete` expressions), a `nullptr` has been dereferenced, the value of an uninitialised variable has been accessed, some code has accessed elements of an array out of bounds.   The cause may be in your containing class, or in some completely unrelated code.\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it possible in C++ that a mere check for nullptr causes such an exception ?

It isn't. The check is not the problem here.

> I mean I am not trying to use the object, I am just checking is the addresss a nullptr.

The pointer is a member of *another* object, which you haven't shown. Most likely *this* (and literally `this`) is where the problem lies.

When you say

> I have a class that has some FFmpeg object as member variable

it tells us that the expression

```
(formatContext != nullptr)
```

is really

```
(this->formatContext != nullptr)
```

and the load of the member variable from `this` is something that could cause an access violation: if either `this` is not a valid pointer (because you incorrectly cast something to a pointer to your class or because prior Undefined Behaviour already trashed your process) or potentially if `this` was already deleted.

Your intuition was correct that the comparison is unlikely to be a problem (the rare exception being platforms with pointer trap representations) - you were just missing the fact that the pointer had to be loaded *from* somewhere to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

The `Invalid argument` exception might be because `&formatContext` is not a pointer to a pointer to a valid object and as such it is an invalid argument to the `avformat_close_input` function.
So the exception might come from that function (use a debugger) and not from the `nullptr` check that should always be valid as you are comparing two pointers (two numbers if the & operator is not overloaded).

Comment: Passing a pointer-to-a-pointer seems to be what the `av_format_close_input()` function expects you to do (presumably so that it can set your pointer to NULL as a side-effect of the call):  https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.4/group__lavf__decoding.html#gae804b99aec044690162b8b9b110236a4